# How to display a control (zoom bar) outside map container in openlayers?

Tags: openlayers-2

Since I'm new to OpenLayers this question might be the simplest of them all but after a quick search on the subject I couldn't find anything useful, so:

Is it possible to put a OpenLayers zoom bar/slider outside the map container in another div? Like for example *OpenLayers.Control.Zoom()*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, create your map with no controls.

```js
var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', { controls: [] });
```

To place the controls outside the map container, create a container `<div>` to put it inside.

```js
<div id="external_control"></div>
```

Then create the controls and place them inside the `#external_control` container.

```js
var external_control = new OpenLayers.Control.Zoom({
    div: document.getElementById('external_control') });

map.addControl(external_control);
```

[This](http://vasir.net/blog/openlayers/openlayers-tutorial-part-3-controls/) tutorial might help you. Specifically, the section on "Adding Controls Outside of Map"

Comment: Funny thing: I had that tutorial open in another browser window already, but I was only on step 2!

Comment: Glad I could keep you aligned with that tutorial. I've used it when I was first starting out with OL.