# Display a control (zoom bar) outside map container in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, mapcontrol

I need to extend a zoom control so that it is functional outside of the leaflet map container.  Can this be done?

Essentially,the same idea as what is accomplished with this item here but under the leaflet context and not openlayers.
[How to display a control (zoom bar) outside map container in openlayers?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30359/how-to-display-a-control-zoom-bar-outside-map-container-in-openlayers)

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, I thought it was something easy to do, but eventually I've lost almost half a day to come up with a solution.

The **[first version](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13060205/Stackexchange/Leaflet_Zoom_Control/leaflet_toolbar.html)** didn't seemed to have a practical use (only proved it is possible),

[image]

but it paved the way for the **[second solution](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13060205/Stackexchange/Leaflet_Zoom_Control/leaflet_toolbar_v2.html)**, that may constitute a basis for interesting future developments.

[image]

The map can be `panned`, `clicked` and the `zoom control` is working properly.
Tested only on `Chrome`, `Firefox`, `Opera` and `Internet Explorer 11`.

Comment: Great work! You fonud an awesome solution. Thanks so much, Sorin!

Comment: Why including links only isnt a good idea. Links are now dead.

Comment: it would be great to include the code. Thanks

Comment: I wish the code were available.