# How to display a control outside map container in openlayers 3.5.0?

Tags: openlayers

I try to associate a control to div with OpenLayers 3.5.0.

I found this [tutorial](http://vasir.net/blog/openlayers/openlayers-tutorial-part-3-controls) and this [subject](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30359/how-to-display-a-control-zoom-bar-outside-map-container-in-openlayers) on GIS SE but the solutions were for OpenLayers 2.
I tried them with OL3 but it doesn't work.

Do you know how can I do that ?

Comment: Perhaps you put an example online, so we can see how to give a hand.

Comment: Of course Jonatas, it's not a reflex for me ;-) [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/6pifmbhhtyDY0CrFkcx2?p=preview)

Comment: Your example seems to work just add the 2nd full screen control to the map.
var ct = new ol.control.FullScreen({target: test_div2});
map.addControl(ct);

Comment: Thank you Oterral, but it doesn't work because what I want, it's, when I click on my div, that's run the fullscreen. That's why I tried to associate the DIV to the control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize what we say in comments and to add a solution:

To put a contol in a custom div use the `target` property of the control:

```
var ctrl= new ol.control.FullScreen({
  target: document.querySelector('#your_div_id')
});
map.addControl(ctrl);
```

To allow the click on your custom div to trigger the control functionnality, you need a bit of CSS:

```
.ol-full-screen {
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.ol-full-screen button{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Tested [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/lZnt9VjXhtnZT6plflso?p=preview)  , I've verified with the console and the click is well triggered.

Comment: It's perfect, than you oterral! good idea to set opacity 0 to the button full-screen